# error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode9, lldb

I am trying to print out the `CMTimeRange` property of an `AVAssetTrack` object.

First, I've tried:

```
(lldb) p videoTrack.timeRange
error: property 'timeRange' not found on object of type 'AVAssetTrack *'
```

Even though it's clearly defined as:

```
@interface AVAssetTrack (AVAssetTrackTemporalProperties)

/* Indicates the timeRange of the track within the overall timeline of the asset;
a track with CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(timeRange.start, >, kCMTimeZero) will initially present an empty interval. */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CMTimeRange timeRange;
```

Anyway, I've tried message passing instead of property access, then I get this:

```
(lldb) p [videoTrack timeRange]
error: no known method '-timeRange'; cast the message send to the method's return type
```

Okay, I cast it to the correct type, `CMTimeRange`, and I get this:

```
(lldb) p (CMTimeRange)[videoTrack timeRange]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

The `videoTrack` in question is a valid object:

```
(lldb) po videoTrack
<AVAssetTrack: 0x1cc00f2f0, trackID = 1, mediaType = vide>
```

Why am I getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation properties of AVAssetTrack are not necessarily available immediately, but are loaded asynchronously when called for or by explicit loading. My guess is that `timeRange` has not yet been loaded when you try to access it, and/or that the debugger interferes with the loading mechanism somehow.

> AVAssetTrack adopts the AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading protocol. You
>   can use the protocol’s statusOfValueForKey:error: method to determine
>   if a track property can be accessed without blocking the calling
>   thread.

If possible either try to pre-load the `timeRange` property well ahead of your breakpoint or put an `NSLog()` in the completion and break on that.

```
[videoTrack loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[ @"timeRange" ] completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"timeRange: %@", videoTrack.timeRange.description);
}];
```

You can also try calling the `statusOfValueForKey:error:` method from the debugger.